# Bull MQ repeatable jobs getting flushed

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, jobs, bull, bullmq

I just deployed my application on Kubernetes with 3 replica set the issue is that my Bull MQ repeatable jobs get lost after few hours I have bull board to see all the jobs.
Anyone faced same kind of issue?

I have 2 queues and 2 workers one for each queue

TIA

Went through all the internet didn't find anything

[My instance giving me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVQxA.jpg)